# Why does the dispersion of X about its conditional mean decreases as the σ−algebra grows?

Tags: pr.probability

Given $ \mathbb{E}X^2<\infty $, how can I show that if two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{G}_1\subset \mathscr{G}_2$, then $\mathbb{E}[Var(X|\mathscr{G}_2)]\leq \mathbb{E}[Var(X|\mathscr{G}_1)]$ ?
I have noticed that $\mathbb{E}[Var(X|\mathscr{G})] = \mathbb{E}X^2-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}^2(X|\mathscr{G})]$ and was thinking of the tower property of conditional expectation in order to use the size relationship between $\sigma$-fields, but I have currently got stuck, and I am wondering how to generate the size relationship between $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}^2(X|\mathscr{G})]$.

Comment: A useful fact is that for square-integrable $X$,  $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is the $L^2$ orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the subspace of $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variables.  In particular, $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ minimizes the $L^2$ distance to that subspace, so if $Y$ is any other $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable, then $\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}])^2] \le E[(X-Y)^2]$.  Now applying this with $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{G}_2$ and $Y = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}_1]$ you should get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\G{\mathscr G}$For $j=1,2$, let $E_j$ and $V_j$ denote, respectively, the conditional expectation and the conditional variance given $\G_j$. Given that $\G_1\subset\G_2$, you want to show that $E V_2 X\le E V_1 X$. You have already established that $E V_j X=EX^2-EY_j^2$ for $j=1,2$, where $Y_j:=E_j X$. So, it is enough to show that $EY_2^2\ge EY_1^2$.

We have $E_1Y_2^2=E^2_1Y_2+V_1 Y_2\ge E^2_1Y_2=Y_1^2$, since $\G_1\subset\G_2$. So, $EY_2^2=EE_1Y_2^2\ge EY_1^2$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your help!